# Save and Restore Layout Manager state attached to recycler view

Tags: android

I know the solution to the asked question is all on the internet! even several methods on stackoverflow, believe me I've read and applied all of it but I'm unable to save and restore my recycler views's scroll position on device rotation.
Here is my code for the same( onCreate and onSaveInstanceState ).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    handleCollapsingToolbarTitle();
    loadViews();
    moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(new ArrayList<Movies>(), this, this, this);
    mlayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    moviesRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    moviesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    moviesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);
    moviesRecyclerView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
    loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
        if(listState != null)
            moviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    // Save list state
    listState = moviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    state.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, listState);
}
```

So I've tried every combination like saving in onPause and restoring in onRestoreInstanceState and onCreate, onResume! But I'm unsuccessful. I don't want to handle it via androidConfigChange tag. Please help me!.
PS: I'm using GridLayoutManager and I've even tried StatefulRecyclerView posted [here](https://gist.github.com/FrantisekGazo/a9cc4e18cee42199a287)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your purpose without saving and restoring the position inside `onSaveInstanceState` You can add the attribute 
`android:launchMode="singleTop"`
inside your activity tag in the manifest file.

Comment: Tried it didn't work. Btw this tag is used to send an intent to a already exisiting activity ( if you're opening that one ) if its on the top of the stack of the caller task.